# Trigger cannot be created in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, debugging, triggers

I'm trying to run this trigger that is suppose to update a row in my customers table after a row is updated in the same table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [project].updateFreeShipping
ON [project].[customers]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [project].[customers]
    SET NextShippingIsFree = 1
    WHERE Email IN (SELECT TOP 5 Email FROM dbo.Top10byMoney)
END
```

It throws the following error:

> Msg 8197, Level 16, State 4, Procedure updateFreeShipping, Line 2
> The object 'project.customers' does not exist or is invalid for this operation

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Your trigger code does not make sense.  For instance, it does not refer to `inserted` or `deleted`.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would all help.

Comment: the part where the table is actually exist

Comment: the idea is that I have a function that calculates a discount rate for some top 10 customers in the table. once the function is updating the column of the 'discount rate' in the customers table the trigger is supposed to be activated and change the 'next shipping is free' column to be '1' for the top 5 customers from that view (top10byminey).

Comment: Nice idea but the whole setup sounds rather suspect. Please edit your post with the rest of the code (the discount function and top10bymoney)

Comment: In your previous question, you did not qualify your table with a schema name and it seems to have worked. You have changed your approach - you will need to figure out why this naming convention is not working. Either your schema name is incorrect or the current database of your query window is not the one with your table. Context is important - you need to make an effort to provide information since others cannot see your screen nor have any knowledge of what you are trying to actually do.

Comment: The subquery you have is pretty suspect as well; with out an `ORDER BY` is free to return any 5 arbitrary rows, which could easily be different rows each time. Add that to that you're updating the entire table every time you update even a single row, and you're going to get some very odd and undesirable behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This is a clear and classical error that is raised when you execute a statement in another database that the one you usually use. Very often, beginners does not verify the contexteual database and try to create objets in master which is the default one in SSMS. Remember that SQL Server is a multi-database multi-schema RDBMS and does not require any DBlink to execute SQL scripts from one DB to another... So make a great attention to which database you contextually use !

To avoid such trouble, begin your script with the USE statement, like :

```
USE MyDatabase;
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [project].updateFreeShipping
ON [project].[customers]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
...
```

I agree to all others comments about the logic of your code which has no sense...